# How do I hide the MS-dos box that appears during IE tab switch?

Tags: internet-explorer, batch-file

First off thanks @sachadee for this IE tab switching script:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.AppActivate "Internet Explorer"
Wscript.Sleep 1500
WshShell.SendKeys "^{TAB}"
Wscript.Sleep 1500
```

This script has helped me in a recent project. **My question is What switch would I use in order to hide the MS-dos box that pops up when the tabs switch?**